# How to remove eyelashes noise using ellipse detection

Tags: computer-vision, scikit-image, hough-transform, noise-reduction, canny-operator

Hopeful end result of detecting ellipse in photo and drawing edges accurately:

[image: Hopeful end result of detecting ellipse in photo and drawing edges accurately]

Picture I'm trying to work with:

[image: Picture I'm trying to work with]

I’m looking to detect the ellipses of an eye in a side view image but one problem is that when I run the canny function and draw the edges it can only draw edges on the eyelashes and make some sort of ellipse there. This noise is also causing problems because in my hough transform ellipse function I am thresholding for all values higher than .9 (and lower than .7) and these values on the eyelashes have the maximum pixel intensity values so they are taken into account.

Is there a way to remove the noise (eyelashes)? I am using skimage from sci-kit image for all of this. This is for a side view of the eye.

Comment: Could you post an image that you are trying to process?

Comment: Yes. I have edited the post so you can see I have uploaded the link for the image. Keep in mind that I even tried to zoom in on the eye and reduces the picture dimensions (x and y) to focus only on the eye.

Comment: are you trying to specifically detect the iris of the eye or you want simply to detect the whole eye?

Comment: how many training/test images do you have?

Comment: I would suggest you to also try out template matching if you are trying to always match eyes on a side profile. For that you can use grayscale or binary image and run the template with opencv for e.g (not sure what skimage equivalent function is, I used it quite some time back). It would help others better answer your question if you also add an image of what you would like your end result to look like.

Comment: I am specifically trying to detect the iris of the eye and the boundary of the inner ellipse (within it) as well. I am not using any training or test data for this as I was instead trying to use a Hough Transform ellipse function for this after feeding in the edges I got from the canny function. Eventually, the main thing I want is to get the centre of the inner ellipse and outer ellipse, or at least the locations of where they are from which I can then extrapolate this data.

Comment: Also I have added the hopeful end result in my edited post, so you can see it now.